# Getting an error while implementing log in with facebook in my web app using php

Tags: php, facebook-login

[image]
Please help me resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Hello it will give you error .

You have to create you app first on facebook developer site and that app should be verified by Facebook.

Please Read the below link which will help you

[Login With Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/requirements)

[Detail](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login)

Answer (score 0):

@user3346547

Please create an app and publish it

You need to add your redirect url in **Valid OAuth redirect URIs** section when you have created your app. It is under **Facebook Login -> Setting**s.

You also need to provide the website url in **Settings-> Basic Setting section**

I think this will surely help